# How do I convert all numeric columns to character type in my dataframe?

Tags: r

I would like to do something more efficient than

```
dataframe$col <- as.character(dataframe$col)
```

since I have many numeric columns.

Comment: Try `dataframe[] <- lapply(dataframe, as.character)` or only for numeric `i1 <- sapply(dataframe, is.numeric);dataframe[i1] <- lapply(dataframe[i1], as.character)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, but I would like to specify only the numeric columns since I have a mixture of other datatypes in the dataframe as well. This would convert the whole dataframe. Is there some way to do this for only numeric columns?

Comment: I updated as a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `base R`, we may either use one of the following i.e. loop over all the columns, create an `if/else` conditon to change it

```
dataframe[] <- lapply(dataframe, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) 
           as.character(x) else x)
```

Or create an index for numeric columns and loop only on those columns and assign

```
i1 <- sapply(dataframe, is.numeric)
dataframe[i1] <- lapply(dataframe[i1], as.character)
```

---

It may be more flexible in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe <- dataframe %>%
        mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.character))
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for @akrun, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

All said by master akrun! Here is a `data.table` alternative. Note it converts all columns to `character` class:

```
library(data.table)
data.table::setDT(df)
df[, (colnames(df)) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = colnames(df)]
```